# How to group multiple arrays by code and then sum them?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have mutiple arrays like this and every this arrays have structure like this:

```
0: Array(3)
0: {code: 0, value: 0}
1: {code: 1, value: 0}
2: {code: 2, value: 0}

1: Array(3)
0: {code: 0, value: 0}
1: {code: 1, value: 0}
2: {code: 2, value: 0}
```

I want to sum every of this ararys by code so that  i will have like this:

total[0] = sum where code == 0;
total[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11ocf.png) = sum where code == 1;
total[2] = sum where code == 2;

```
     this.obj.row1.map((a: any) => { this.obj['total'][this.column] += a[this.column].value; });
     this.obj.row2.map((a: any) => { this.obj['total'][this.column] += a[this.column].value; });
     this.obj.row3.map((a: any) => { this.obj['total'][this.column] += a[this.column].value; });
```

Any suggestion how can i achive this??
[image]

This is my two arrays:

```
   array1: [[{"code":0,"value":1},{"code":1,"value":0},{"code":2,"value":0}],[{"code":0,"value":0},{"code":1,"value":0},{"code":2,"value":0}],[{"code":0,"value":0},{"code":1,"value":0},{"code":2,"value":0}],[{"code":0,"value":0},{"code":1,"value":0},{"code":2,"value":0}]]

 array2:   [[{"code":0,"value":0},{"code":1,"value":0},{"code":2,"value":0}],[{"code":0,"value":0},{"code":1,"value":0},{"code":2,"value":0}],[{"code":0,"value":0},{"code":1,"value":0},{"code":2,"value":0}]]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect `totals` of same `code`. At the end render a new array.

```js
var array = [[{ code: 0, value: 1 }, { code: 1, value: 2 }, { code: 2, value: 3 }], [{ code: 2, value: 1 }, { code: 0, value: 2 }, { code: 0, value: 3 }]],
    result = Array.from(
        array.flat().reduce((m, { code, value }) => m.set(code, (m.get(code) || 0) + value), new Map),
        ([code, total]) => ({ code, total })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: inside every of this array i have array , and because of that when i use your code i get code undefined and total NaN

Comment: i put image how structture of array looks like

Comment: it works when i pass one array but when i try to pass mutliple arrays like this:  let array = this.obj.row1, this.obj.row_0, is say :
Variable declaration expected. If i add all of this in [ this.obj.row1, this.obj.row_0] i dont get any errors but again i get code undefined and total NaN.

Comment: maybe it is easier, if you add a small amount of the object/arrays in text form.

Comment: what u mean? to fix array values or ?

Comment: i mean the image, you supplied is like i view through a keyhole, but your comments and code above states objects (`row1`, and so on). please add the data in text form/literal notation to the question (and it would not hurt, if you add the result as well).

Comment: i posted examples of my two arrays...other arrays looks like that it just that have more objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199068/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-none).

Comment: if you don't know how to combine two arrays, you should learn it first. Otherwise try this: combinedArrays = array1.concat(array2, array3, and, so, on); after you've done this: apply ninas answer.

Comment: i just added let merged = [].concat.apply([], [this.obj.row1, this.obj.row2]); and then pass the to var array and its working :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 x={0:[{code: 0, value: 25},
       {code: 1, value: 10},
       {code: 2, value: 5}],
   1: [{code: 0, value: 3},
      {code: 1, value: 2},
      {code: 2, value: 6}]
                      }
keys=Object.keys(x)
value=[0,0,0]
for (i in key){
  for(j in x[i]){
    value[x[i][j].code]+=x[i][j].value;
   }
 }
 console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nina Scholz's answer, to achieve your desired result

1. total[0] = sum where code == 0;
2. total1 = sum where code == 1;
3. total[2] = sum where code == 2;

just map ninas result like this:

```js
 const test = [[{ code: 0, value: 1 }, { code: 1, value: 2 }, { code: 2, value: 3 }], [{ code: 2, value: 1 }, { code: 0, value: 2 }, { code: 0, value: 3 }]];

const total = Array.from(
        test.flat().reduce((m, { code, value }) => m.set(code, (m.get(code) || 0) + value), new Map),
        ([code, total]) => ({ code, total })
    ).map(x => x.total)
    
    
console.log(total[0]);
console.log(total[1]);
console.log(total[2]);
```